# an error while accessing data connection in infopath

Tags: infopath

I got permission issue to access the connection file during browsing the infopath form

**the file cannot be found or you don't have permission**

I checked the library and the file is found and i have permission to access it

what other setting do i have ?

Comment: Is the data connection library and the form library is located in the same site collection?

Comment: I think yes, let me check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's not a permission issue because you already have access to the file as you have mentioned in your question.

So in your case, just make sure that the data connection library and the form library is located in the same site collection.

- The `data connection library` that holds the connection file must be in the same site collection that contains the `form library` that holds your InfoPath form.